# Disabling asset bundling in production, Rails 3.1?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

I have an existing Rails application I am upgrading to Rails 3.1 from Rails 3.0.  All is going well in development, but when moving to production my stylesheets are breaking, apparently due to asset compilation.

I would like to disable asset compilation in production until I can get the stylesheet conflicts worked out, but the config switches I throw at it dont seem to be working.

*production.rb*

```
# Don't fallback to assets pipeline
config.assets.compile = false

# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Generate digests for assets URLs
config.assets.digest = false
```

After restarting Passenger application.css is the only stylesheet being served, contains inline content.  In the development environment I have:

*development.rb*

```
# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true
```

...which leads to several stylesheets being loaded, not just application.css, and working styles in the application.

*application.rb*

```
=stylesheet_link_tag 'application'
=javascript_include_tag 'application'
```

*application.css*

```
*= require flutie
*= require_self
*= require jquery-ui-1.8.14.custom.css
*= require demo_table
```

All assets are setup in app/assets

Answer (score 6):

In your application.rb you need to disable it.  If you want it to be like this in production **only** leave it as true in your application.rb and just put the config.assets.enabled = false in your production.rb

```
# Enable the asset pipeline
config.assets.enabled = false
```

Comment: Hmmm, thanks Nick, I set config.assets_enabled false in application.rb and true in production.rb, now im getting entirely broken stylesheets and js.  Says it cant find application.js and application.css

Comment: You could try changing the line:
  config.assets.compile = false to be true.  This will compile any stylesheets or javascript whenever something is missed.

Comment: Already set to false.    # Don't fallback to assets pipeline
  config.assets.compile = false

  # Do not compress assets
  config.assets.compress = false

  # Generate digests for assets URLs
  config.assets.digest = false
  
  # Enable the asset pipeline
  config.assets.enabled = false

Comment: Did you compile your assets at deployment? **RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile**

Comment: That didnt get it either.  The problem is its still bundling everything as application.css, which leads to broken CSS everywhere.  Ahh well, thanks for your help anyway Nick, I'm surrendering on this for now and will just fix the CSS

Comment: Well that's what it is supposed to do.  I'm not sure what your css looks like, but I'd read through the [Rails Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html)

Comment: you should move all the assets in app/assets folder to the public directory and include them manually in your layouts.